# No longer able to paste into dialog boxes created in automator. Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: automator

I have built hundreds of Automator scripts which allow the user to paste clipboard data into a dialog box.  I'm now running Automator Version 2.9 (444.42) and Mac OS 10.14.5 and can no longer do this.

1. Create a simple application
2. Using `Ask for text` and running the application within Automator, I can successfully paste text from my clipboard into the dialog box.
3. If I save this and try launching this application from the finder, I can type into this dialog box, but cannot paste into it.

Points of data: Applications I wrote in the past continue to work on this machine (i.e,, they accept pasted text).

Newly written applications will not.

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

I am also experiencing the same problem after putting your dilemma to the test within Automator.  However, I did come up with a workaround which seems to work for me.

In Script Editor.app, paste this following AppleScript code into a new document and tweak the code to suit your needs.  Next, save this Script Editor doc as an application.

```
activate
set theAnswer to text returned of (display dialog "Answer This Question" default answer ¬
    "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 cancel button 1 with title ¬
    "Ask For Text" with icon 1 giving up after 20 without hidden answer)

set the clipboard to theAnswer
```

Be sure to add this new app to allow access to control your computer in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility and Full Disk Access menu items.

[image]

Now instead of inserting a "Ask For Text" command into your Automator workflow, add a "Launch Application" command instead and choose your new application you just created in Script Editor.  Now because of the AppleScript code, which copies the results of the text entered in the dialog box, to the clipboard... You now have a way of passing the results as a variable into the rest of your Automator workflow.

[image]

After saving the Automator workflow as an application and running the new app outside of Automator, I was able to successfully paste the text into the dialog box.

---

---

**UPDATE
Option 2**

This following option will not work if you save your Automator workflow as an application. If you save your Automator workflow that contains the "Ask For Text" command, as a workflow and not as an application, you can run Apple scripts or Automator workflows directly from the Script menu in the menu bar (without having to launch Automator or Script Editor to run the files).  **This option will allow you to paste into your "Ask For Text" dialog box.**

To be able to do this, you need to make sure, in Script Editor.app's General Preferences, the "Show Script menu in the menu bar" option is checked.

[image]

To be able to access these scripts and workflows directly in the script menu bar, they need to be saved to this folder... /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Scripts

I save all of my Apple scripts and Automator workflows in a specific location which is not in my /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Scripts folder.  I prefer to make an alias file of the script or workflow using Finder's "Make Alias" command in the contextual menu, and move that alias file to my /Users/YOUR SHORT NAME/Library/Scripts folder instead.  This way all of my scripts remain in their preferred original locations and I can delete the alias files anytime I want, leaving the originals untouched.

You can easily locate the correct folder to place your scripts or workflows files, or aliases to those files, as demonstrated in this following image.

[image]

This next animation shows how easy it is to run the workflow now, directly from the script menu. And the nice thing about running the file as a workflow and not an application is that as long as Automator is granted access to control your computer in your System Preferences...  There's no need to go through the process of granting every application created in Automator, access privileges.

[image]

Comment: That's clever, and would be a good fit if I were a one person operation.  The apps I'm building get used company wide, so I may just get a dedicated machine that's pre-mojave and use it for my final builds

Comment: @RichCraig I added an update with a second option that works out pretty well, which should avoid you having to "get a dedicated machine that's pre-mojave and use it for my final build"

Comment: It turns out it's just pasting via *Command-V*, that doesn't work with Mojave.  While not as straight forward, you can right click and choose paste, and it will fill the dialog box with the clipboard.

Comment: I have the following issue with your option 1: When I call the App from Automator, the dialog shows, but Automator does not wait for the value to be entered in the dialog. After calling the app to show the dialog, it immediately continues with the following step.